# How to mark members that are required by runtime but shouldn't be used in code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, properties

Sometimes the .NET runtime requires us to create public setters for properties which should really be read-only.  For example:

1. XmlSerializer requires serialized properties to be writable, even if we only serialize one-way.
2. I have an unusual case in WPF where I need to have a TwoWay binding within a MultiBinding, even though conceptually the bound value will never change.  This requires properties to be writable.

In each of these cases, I can leave the setter empty without affecting the functionality, but this is likely to lead to confusion down the line.

Given that I can't avoid having public setters on these properties, is there a way to generate compiler warnings when the setters are accessed?  The attributes `[Deprecated]` and `[Obsolete]` would do the job, but the wording/intent isn't right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I approach this problem is that I simply don't compromise the integrity my types for the purposes of serialization.  The process of serialization is all about data and very little about behavior.  I refuse to compromise the behavior of my types for a data only scenario.

Instead I design my types for the most efficient + safe usage.  If the resulting type is not serializable and I find a scenario that requires it, I will create separate types which exist solely for the purpose of serializing my other types.

Here's a quick sample.

```
// My Core Immutable Type
namespace MyProject {
  public sealed class Student { 
    private readonly string _name;
    public string Name { 
      get { return _name; }
    }
    public Student(string name) {
      _name = name;
    }
  }
}

// My Xml Serialization Type
namespace MyProject.Serialization {
  public class SerializableStudent {
    public string Name;

    public SerializableStudent(Student source) {
      Name = source.Name;
    }

    public Student ConvertToStudent() {
      return new Student(Name);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean that your separate types also have setters which don't do anything?

Comment: @Greg, my serialization types often have very different hierarchies than the originals.  I optimize them for data types and just add the information necessary to serialize the data and convert to / from the original types

Comment: I agree with you completely, but in this case I'm struggling to find a solution which doesn't require a setter which should never be called - I guess that's where I should focus my efforts, but in the meantime I'll leave the question open.

Comment: @Greg, added an example of what I mean with XML serialization.

Comment: I've accepted this as the answer because it provides sound advice which probably explains why such an attribute doesn't exist.

Answer (score -2):

For serialization, specifically, you can define the process manually by implementing the ISerializable interface.

Comment: -1: The question itself has nothing to do with serialization.